# How does topography affect composite SLA?

Tags: amazon-ecs, kafka, sla

I looked at [How do you calculate the compound Service Level Agreement (SLA) for cloud services?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/711) and am still not sure how **topography** affects SLA. Suppose a request...

1. passes through one instance of Service A, where all Services have SLA `s`
2. resulting in concurrent work items on Kafka topics K1 and K2, where Kafka has SLA `k`
3. which get consumed concurrently by Services B1 and B2 respectively (B1 consumes K1; B2 consumes K2)
4. which both send their results via a third Kafka topic K3
5. and all 3 services (A, B1, B2) read and write a common DB with SLA `d`

Suppose this is all in the same availability zone. Here are some questions I have:

1. Does the SLA for Kafka only figure into the calculation *once*? I'm guessing Kafka is either up or down for the entire AZ, so it doesn't matter how many Kafka topics I use, connecting however many components.
2. Does the SLA for AWS ECS microservices figure into the calculation as many times as they appear on my execution path according to [the SLA question referenced above](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/711) which explains how to calculate for serial and parallel paths?
3. Does the SLA for the DB appear along each execution path *separately* like in #2 above for the microservices? Or is it more like Kafka, affecting the entire AZ?

Comment: this might be a duplicate of https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-do-you-calculate-the-compound-service-level-agreement-sla-for-cloud-servic ?

Comment: I always assume that the SLA of a whole system is no better than the lowest SLA provided by any of its composite parts across all regions and data-centres. No need to do any complicated maths. e.g. if you have a thousand components with 99.999999% uptime, and a DB with 50% uptime and your app relies on that DB, then your app has a maximum uptime of 50%. No need for any math at all. Unless you're reducing that yourself by doing something that restricts your ability to take advantage of the 50%.

Comment: @BruceBecker I edited my questions to further distinguish them from the one we both linked to, see especially #3.

To "Software Engineer": the composite SLA can be much worse than the lowest single SLA: https://youtu.be/syi3_ePY4Ic